# Playing hi-res flv files

Tags: flv

What is the best way to play hi-res flv clips ?
Frame size is 1650x1050 pixels and it runs for about 2-3 seconds.
I am downloading the file before playing, but it drops frames and not running smoothly.
Is this an encoding issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Flash video is very processor-intensive to decode, so it's most likely not a broken video. You're probably just putting too much load on the CPU.

Since you're working with video at that resolution, you should use a different container and codec format, such as H.264 wrapped in an MKV.

Comment: You can put H.264 in a FLV as well (that's what youtube does for their HD videos). Flash still uses way too much CPU for video playing though.